# Table column should not move along with table body on vertical scroll bar

Tags: jsp

1. I am using table tag in jsp.
2. I applied horizontal scroll bar and vertical scroll bar to that table.
3. When I scroll vartical scroll bar at bottom at that time column name also goes up along with table body.
4. But I dont want like this, when I scroll bottom using vertical scroll bar table columns should not move with table body. It should be fixed on that position only.

Answer (score 0):

This is the time you need to think about using plugins like [jQgrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), [table fixed header](http://www.tablefixedheader.com/), [DataTable](http://datatables.net/). These are requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin.

The Reasons are,

1. the horizontal, vertical scolling management
2. a pager
3. sortable columns
4. resizable columns
5. full compatibility with jQuery UI

Or you can use [Display Tags](http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-paging.jsp). Hope it helps.